# Make JSON Consistent format - Pyspark

Tags: json, pyspark, explode

Two json's which are in different format , convert to a single consistent format and read into dataframe .

```
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- ReplicateRequest: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- MappingReplicateRequestMessage: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- MGroup: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Object: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Code: string (nullable = true)


df1.printSchema()
root
 |-- ReplicateRequest: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- MappingReplicateRequestMessage: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- MGroup: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Object: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Code: string (nullable = true)
```

If i want to access  **Object.code** column value :

1. In first dataframe , i have to use explode on MappingReplicateRequestMessage to drill it down .

`df.select("ReplicateRequest.*").withColumn("expl",explode((col("MappingReplicateRequestMessage")))).select("expl.*").select("MGroup.Object")`

2. in Second dataframe  i can directly access without explode .

`df1.select("ReplicateRequest.MappingReplicateRequestMessage.MGroup.*")`

How do i make it consistent and generic from converting to Array to Struct or Struct to Array before parsing

Comment: Explode `df` and perform a `union` operation on top of `df` and `df1`. In this case you can use `Object.code` to retrieve the data.

Comment: before parsing we need to check if its an array or struct , that check we need to eliminate and make it consistent , is there any way to avoid and make a single format out of two

Comment: What do you mean by parsing here?

Comment: df=spark.read.json('file.json)  ,  there might be N no of file located in s3 bucket , you need to read each file and parse the content ,  it might be struct or array , the agenda is to make either struct or array ( single consistent format)

Answer (score 0):

You can not read two files with different schema, into a single `DataFrame`, using a single `spark.read` call.

You will have to read them in two different `DataFrame`s, manipulate each `DataFrame` to create new DataFrame with the common schema you want and then union them.

```py
df1 = spark.read.csv/parquet/json()
df1 = df1.withColumn('new_json', <logic to convert>)

df2 = spark.read.csv/parquet/json()
df2 = df2.withColumn('new_json', <logic to convert>)

final_df = df1.union(df2)
```

---

it might also be possible to read the input as string

```
root
 |-- ReplicateRequest: string (nullable = true)
```

and then apply a udf that can handle two different formats, extract `Object.code` and return it so that you end up with a new column that has a uniform schema. Need reproducible example for it.

---

Add sample data to your example and make it a reproducible example, like this:

```py
jstr1 = u'{"header":{"id":12345,"foo":"bar"},"body":{"id":111000,"name":"foobar","sub_json":{"id":54321,"sub_sub_json":{"col1":20,"col2":"somethong"}}}}'
jstr2 = u'{"header":{"id":12346,"foo":"baz"},"body":{"id":111002,"name":"barfoo","sub_json":{"id":23456,"sub_sub_json":{"col1":30,"col2":"something else"}}}}'
jstr3 = u'{"header":{"id":43256,"foo":"foobaz"},"body":{"id":20192,"name":"bazbar","sub_json":{"id":39283,"sub_sub_json":{"col1":50,"col2":"another thing"}}}}'

df = spark.createDataFrame([(jstr1,),(jstr2,),(jstr3,)], schema=['col1'])
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Prints:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|col1                                                                                                                                                |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"header":{"id":12345,"foo":"bar"},"body":{"id":111000,"name":"foobar","sub_json":{"id":54321,"sub_sub_json":{"col1":20,"col2":"somethong"}}}}      |
|{"header":{"id":12346,"foo":"baz"},"body":{"id":111002,"name":"barfoo","sub_json":{"id":23456,"sub_sub_json":{"col1":30,"col2":"something else"}}}} |
|{"header":{"id":43256,"foo":"foobaz"},"body":{"id":20192,"name":"bazbar","sub_json":{"id":39283,"sub_sub_json":{"col1":50,"col2":"another thing"}}}}|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```